# Confuse about the name of EventWaitHandle

Tags: c#, .net, api, event-wait-handle

Considering below code snippet for MyServer side

```
public void CreateEvent()
{
   var serverReadyEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "aaa");
}
```

After search from MSDN, the 3rd parameter of the ctor means

> name
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The name of a system-wide synchronization event.

But I find that I can call the method **CreateEvent** for multiple times and without any exception, is this mean that there are multiple EventWaitHandle instances exist with the same name? Is this correct behavior?

And below is the code snippet on MyClient side

```
public void OpenEvent()
{
     EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting("aaa");
}
```

If the **CreateEvent** was called in MyServer side for 2 times, then in the MyClient side which event will be opened after **OpenEvent** was called?

Comment: It is a *handle* to an event. Multiple handles can exist to the same event.

Comment: It is correct behavior.  The odds that your code will behave correctly are however very slim.  It is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [the documentation for `CreateEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The documentation for the `lpName` parameter states:

> If lpName matches the name of an existing named event object, this
>   function requests the EVENT_ALL_ACCESS access right. In this case, the
>   bManualReset and bInitialState parameters are ignored because they
>   have already been set by the creating process.

So you can see that if the event already exists, a handle to the existing one will be returned.

Therefore only one event exists, and the answer to your question about which one is opened is "the one and only event that was created".